# Python & MongoDB - Store data in descending order

Tags: python, mongodb, sorting

I am using MongoDB with Python. I used the following command to insert my documents:

```
db.test.insert_one({"Name": name, "Age": age})
```

(`name` and `age` are variables within my code)

I used the following command to sort from oldest age to youngest:

```
db.test.find().sort("Age", 1)
```

I understand that I am simply issuing a find command within my code. Is there a clever way to use the `db.test.save()` method to sort my documents and overwrite the original with the sorted documents?

I looked into many questions that somewhat address this problem such as this:
[How to store sorted array back to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120825/how-to-store-sorted-array-back-to-mongodb)

But in order to do the `$push` command inside `update_one` and use the `$sort` feature, I would have to re-work my entire code. What are my options? Do I have to re-work my code or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two concepts in mongo: sorting an array embedded in a document and sorting documents in a collection by some properties.

The post you link to refers to the former. You seem to be trying to permanently sort the documents in a collection.

Mongo stores documents in roughly the order they are written in. Like most databases it uses indexes to make retrieving data more efficient.

In the instance you describe, you would create an index on the age property of your document.

Use either the ensure_index or create_index functions:

```
db.test.ensure_index("Age", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

Henceforth, every query like

```
db.test.find().sort("Age", -1)
```

uses the index and will be very fast.

I suppose you could could try rewriting the documents to another collection in sorted prefer and then see whether a simple fetch always comes back on age order. But this really isn't the right way to be thinking about mongo.

Comment: I think the way I have to approach it is to sort my data and store it into another collection. How would I do that?

Comment: You do the query as you did and insert those docs in another collection. But I've never seen anyone use mongo like that.

Comment: What would be the proper way to use mongo? I'm trying to pull the data from the db into a front end using ExpressJS. Should I stop doing what I'm doing and just sort the data while querying into the front-end?

Comment: The proper way is to create an index and use the find function just the way you did. Perhaps you aren't explaining what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I got it to do what I wanted by creating an index just like you wrote. Thank you!